# Limit Product Qty on SquareSpace Product

Tags: squarespace

I am trying to limit the qty a customer can order using the below script.  The script is supposed to change the quantity input to have max="5", but it is not working.

Is the issue with my code, or something to do with SquareSpace?  I do know that the page loads with max="9999" by default, is there something I'm missing to override that?

```
<script>
   var qty = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]');
   qty.setAttribute('max', '5'); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it sorted.  Needed to checks that the document has fully loaded before running the code. (also, shouldn't have querySelectorAll, just querySelector)

```
<script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            var qty = document.querySelector('input[type="number"]');
              qty.setAttribute('max', '5'); 
        });
</script>
```